# Parsing JSON with generics

Tags: parsing, json, ios, generics, swift

I get back two dictionaries, I need to parse through them and put in an array two objects. I think I did a very poor job and I have a feeling there is a better way to make the code more compact and generic.

I think there is definitely a way to combine these two loops.  Please advise on any better way to accomplish this:

```
var cases = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var statuses = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var retVal = [AnyObject]()
var dict = [String: AnyObject]()    

if jsonReturnValue != nil {
        let (hasError, errorMessage) =  ErrorHandler.hasError(jsonReturnValue)

        if hasError {
            //TODO Display a proper error to the user
            )
            print("Error Message: \(errorMessage)")
        } else {
            for value in jsonReturnValue {
                for (var i = 0; i < value.1.count; i++) {

                    if let dataDict = value.1 as? [String: AnyObject] {

                        let status = dataDict["status"]
                        let case = dataDict["case"]

                        // I think I can combine the two loops below but not sure how.

                        if let val = status as? [AnyObject] {
                            if let items = val[i] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                                for item in items {
                                    dict[item.0] = item.1
                                }
                            }
                            cases.append(dict)
                        }

                        dict.removeAll()

                        if let val = case as? [AnyObject] {
                            if let items = val[i] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                                for item in items {
                                    dict[item.0] = item.1
                                }
                            }
                            statuses.append(dict)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    retVal.removeAll()
    retVal.append(cases)
    retVal.append(statuses)
    return retVal
 }
```

Comment: Some more information would be useful. What type has `jsonReturnValue` and what does it (typically) contain? Where does `ErrorHandler.hasError()` come from?

Comment: Only post compiling code to Code Review: Define `jsonReturnValue`, `ErrorHandler`, the enclosing function and use something other than `case` for your variable since `case` is a keyword and can't be used.